# $_POST from a Meta Box

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, metabox

From my reading, the editor page of a post is wrapped in a form tag meaning a standard HTML form won't work within a Meta Box.

What I'm trying to achieve is a meta box with two fields e.g. Name & Email and a button. When the button is pressed, a POST request will be sent. I can't use AJAX in this instance.

I can render the meta box and a button, along with a simple href link, but is there a way to generate an HTML form, or an alternative method, to replicate POST functionality?

Example Code, I've removed some of the hooks for brevity.

```
function lx_add_paperwork_meta_box() {
            add_meta_box(
                'my_meta_location',
                'Generate Paperwork',
                'display_generate_button',
                'document',
                'side',
                'default'
            );
}

function display_generate_button() {

    output_generate_button( __( 'Create Paperwork', 'my-invoices' ), 0, 'paperwork-generate', array( 'class="button"' ) );

}


function output_generate_button( $title = 'Create', $order_id = 0, $action = 'none', 
    $attributes = array() ) {

            $url = wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( array(
                'post'         => $order_id,
                'action'       => 'edit',
                'paperwork_action' => $action,
            ), admin_url( 'post.php' ) ), $action, 'nonce' );

            $attr_title = $title;

            printf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" %3$s>%4$s</a>', $url, $attr_title, join( ' ', $attributes ), $title );

}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use AJAX to handle your metabox submission then you're going to have to use the submission form. If you don't want your post to actually save maybe you can use an early hook and redirect it back to itself after you process your fields. Would that be an option?

Comment: Thanks, Howdy, I'll consider that. My other option is to generate a link to an entirely separate plugin that simply displays a form and can pull in the post data to then post. Its two steps but it seem like an easier option.